People skipping between dimensions encounter an alien monster
In this movie, the title was one word I believe but could be wrong.
There is a scene with a girl and a guy who ends up on a spaceship (through being transported/teleported through space/time/dimensions, almost like a computer game or famous movie scene this being very similar parody of Alien (Ridley Scott). 
And there are aliens, I remember there was a large human-sized alien and a small or several small facehugger-type looking aliens that were more squidish in apprence,the gets on the girl's head to tries to lay an egg in her and the guy saves her by pulling the thing off or killing it. 
They weren't there for long but they had to hit the remote/device to jump out of scene/dimension so they didn't get killed, something about being trapped,trying to escape. They may have been others in their group.
The movie had reasonable effects and animatronics. It seemed like a sci-fi comedy horror. It was either 80s or 90s (likely 90s)and I viewed it in the UK. The background was that they had like a remote or device that was jumping them around different dimensions or maybe time travel because I remember the were in the past then present then future in space which is were the aliens show up.
My brother rented it on VHS some years ago (1980-2000)it was a movie. It was either they jumped dimensions or between famous movie scenes or through points in time.due to a device/remote.
Likely candidate: Wax Work 2
**Not:**Time Chashers* or eXistenZ or Dr Who or Contamination or Alien Intruder or Stay Tuned or Remote Control or Dead Space or Red Dwarf Or Alien/Aliens/Alien3 or any of it's spin off Prometheus etc. Unlikely to be a Roger Corman film.
Possible movies: The Time Shifters, Future Sport, Virus, Crossworlds, The Arrival, Imposter, Arcade. Avalon. Trapped In Space. Dark Side of The Moon. Peacemaker.

There were many, many Alien rip-offs. Please add any background detail that you can possibly remember: Approximate year of release, country\language, when\where you saw it, what the characters looked like, the tone (you mentioned parody, so was it an actual comedy or was it played straight?), other scenes\plot details you might remember etc.

This reminds me of Josh Kirby... Time Warrior. Do the DVD covers at https://i.sstatic.net/uzDOc.jpg look familiar?

The one on the far bottom left looks familiar & it does seem to fit some of the discription I've given however unless any of the movies seen in photo contain a scene as described above, then it is not the film I'm thinking of, all I can remember is that the cover was artwork(painted etc) & not a photo so I have no idea if it is any these movies but I'm pretty sure it was a sci fi/horror/comedy movie.thanks for the help

The description part with the remote and dimensions sounds a lot like the series Sliders. Any chance you're confusing multiple things? Maybe it's been just some random episode?

Yes I'm sure it does mention in the comments that I didn't believe it was a series,it's not sliders it was a movie my brother rented on VHS some years ago, I've quizzed my brother mutliple times he only rents movies, it actually sounds a lot like TimeChasers so I'll be checking that movie next.thanks tho of you can find a episode match to mine deception let me know but it's unlikely

I seriously doubt this is Time Chasers, though. I don't remember them being in space and encountering an alien at all, they just go back and forth in time. Have you ruled out the Alien spoof in Waxwork II, BTW?

Well Time Chasers fits the deception & plot quite well, I had not thought of waxwork as I have seen the first one & nothing like space aliens there but could be second one,tho due to it not been a space movie didn't think it would apply. It's possible that the movie is Avalon or arcade due to the teleporting place to place & being in a different reality. I'll try waxwork 2 thanks but continue checking other titles.

This movie is Waxwork II: Lost In Time.
The jumping around time/dimensions is a compass device that opens a gate into another reality, which in this movie are famous movie scenes like from The Excorist or Aliens. In this one scene the girl goes through a time door first ending up in space where as the guy ends up in a black & white movie in a haunted house. They rejoin later in the movie.
It has Camoes by Bruce Campbell, as well as many others.
Great movie, thanks to Walt for finding it.
